# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/fontbox/afm/FontMetric

Tags: java, eclipse, pdfbox

I am  using pdfbox-0.7.3.jar. I know missing related class files belongs to JAR pdfbox-0.7.3 but when i attach the source file. keep showing missing .class files. i am seeking for suggestions on the below error.

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
    import org.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
    import org.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
    import org.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;
    import java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError;
    import java.util.Scanner;
        public class ggg{
        public static void main(String args[]) {
           // PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = null;
               // PDDocument pdDoc = null;
           // COSDocument cosDoc = null;
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\firstfile.pdf");
            try {
                PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
                parser.parse();
                COSDocument   cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
                PDFTextStripper   pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                PDDocument pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc); 
                pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
                pdfStripper.setEndPage(5);
                String parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
                System.out.println(parsedText);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/fontbox/afm/FontMetric
    at org.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.getAFM(PDFont.java:334)
    at org.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont.getFontHeight(PDSimpleFont.java:104)
    at org.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.showString(PDFStreamEngine.java:336)
    at org.pdfbox.util.operator.ShowTextGlyph.process(ShowTextGlyph.java:80)
    at org.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:452)
    at org.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:215)
    at org.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:174)
    at org.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.processPage(PDFTextStripper.java:336)
    at org.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.processPages(PDFTextStripper.java:259)
    at org.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.writeText(PDFTextStripper.java:216)
    at org.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.getText(PDFTextStripper.java:149)
    at ggg.main(ggg.java:30)
```

Comment: You need to add this library to your classpath. Which build tool do you use?

Comment: You added this jar into build path but still getting error?

Comment: @nikita_pavlenko yes, i did add in my classpath only properties-->javabuildpath-->libraries-->external jars. Apache PDFBox, IDE eclipse.

Comment: @yılmaz yes, same error.

Comment: Why would you use 0.7.3? This is 10 years old. Current version is 2.0.6, the API is simpler, use `PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);` to open a file. And you'll need fontbox of the same version too.

Comment: It works well. but i started using maven with updated version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you are not using any build tool.

Unfortunately, this library has additional dependencies.

> **org.fontbox.afm.FontMetric** is a class that is located in fontbox-0.1.0.jar

You can go to [Maven Central - PDF Box](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/pdfbox/pdfbox/0.7.3) and download and add all libraries mentioned in dependencies to your project.

[image]

What else you can do is to setup a maven project. And add this dependency to your pom.xml. To do this you need:

1. Install [maven](https://maven.apache.org/)
2. Create a project using maven command line command

   mvn -B archetype:generate \
     -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
     -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app \
     -DartifactId=my-app
3. Add maven PDF dependency to pom.xml file to the section `<dependendencies>`

   `<dependency>
           <groupId>pdfbox</groupId>
           <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
           <version>0.7.3</version>
       </dependency>`
4. Open your generated project as a Maven project inside your IDE (in your case it is Eclipse)
5. Refresh project in IDE and let Eclipse download library with all dependencies for you.

Comment: can suggest similar APIs instead using Maven.

Comment: @vasam you can use same API, just add following libraries to your project. You can follow links and press "Download Jar" button
[jar 1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/bouncycastle/bcmail-jdk14/136),
[jar 2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk14/136),
[jar 3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.fontbox/fontbox/0.1.0),
[jar 4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jempbox/jempbox/0.2.0),

Comment: @vasam Did it help?

Comment: @vasam I think it is more "mature" way of developing application ;)
you can also try [InteliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) which has better support of maven than Eclipse has

Comment: error is Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" with elipse when i try to build dependencies but its irrelevant error. Build success for PDFbox jar. If eclipse doesnt work. i will use InteliJ IDEA but i got it for one month version only. I am looking for full edition as personal usage.