# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.fontbox.afm.AFMParser.parse()V

Tags: java

I'm having an error while using the apache PDFBox jar. It seems like somehow it is calling a method on the AFMParser class which is non-existent. AFAIK I have included fontbox properly. pdfbox,fontbox,commons and gson are all in my build path.

I guess the error must have something to do with referencing, but this is my first JAVA project and no real clue how to debug this further. If anyone has an idea, please advice.

Error log:

```
2018-03-16 14:26:50.020 java[1898:217675] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.fontbox.afm.AFMParser.parse()V
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.addAdobeFontMetric(PDFont.java:166)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.addAdobeFontMetric(PDFont.java:152)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.getAdobeFontMetrics(PDFont.java:122)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.<clinit>(PDFont.java:114)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createFont(PDFontFactory.java:108)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.getFonts(PDResources.java:213)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.getFonts(PDFStreamEngine.java:612)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.operator.SetTextFont.process(SetTextFont.java:69)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:562)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:269)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:236)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:216)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:139)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.print(PDPage.java:890)
    at java.desktop/sun.lwawt.macosx.CPrinterJob$6.run(CPrinterJob.java:757)
    at java.desktop/sun.lwawt.macosx.CPrinterJob.printAndGetPageFormatArea(CPrinterJob.java:767)
    at java.desktop/sun.lwawt.macosx.CPrinterJob.printLoop(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/sun.lwawt.macosx.CPrinterJob.print(CPrinterJob.java:334)
    at java.desktop/sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(RasterPrinterJob.java:1443)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.print(PDDocument.java:1545)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.silentPrint(PDDocument.java:1531)
    at com.xlshopgroup.printingpc.WatchFolder.printPDFFromURL(WatchFolder.java:83)
    at com.xlshopgroup.printingpc.WatchFolder.main(WatchFolder.java:118)
Exception: Error: End-of-File, expected line
```

My code:

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Book;
import java.awt.print.*;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import javax.print.PrintService;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*;   
import org.apache.pdfbox.PrintPDF; 
import org.apache.commons.*; 
import org.apache.fontbox.*;

import com.google.gson.*;

public class WatchFolder {

public static JsonObject sendPost(
        String APIURL
) throws Exception {

    String APIBASEURL = "http://example.com";
    URL obj = new URL(APIBASEURL+APIURL);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    //HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");

    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.flush();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    JsonObject convertedObject = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), JsonObject.class);
    return convertedObject;

}

public static void printPDFFromURL(
        String pdfURL,
        String printerName
) throws IOException,PrinterException {

    PDDocument document         = null;

    try {
        document = PDDocument.load(new URL(pdfURL));
        PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
            printJob.setJobName(pdfURL);

        if(printerName != null ) {
            PrintService[] printService = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
                boolean printerFound = false;
                for(int i = 0;!printerFound && i < printService.length; i++) {
                    if(printService[i].getName().indexOf(printerName) != -1) {
                        printJob.setPrintService(printService[i]);
                        printerFound = true;
                    System.out.println("Printer found: " + printService[i].getName());
                    }
                }
        }

        document.silentPrint( printJob );

    }catch(Exception e) {

        System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());

    }finally {

        if(document != null) {

            document.close();

        }

    }

}

public static void main(
        String[] args
) throws Exception {

    JsonObject toBePrinted  = sendPost("gettoprint");
    JsonObject response     = toBePrinted.getAsJsonObject("response");
    JsonArray  results      = response.getAsJsonArray("results");

    for (JsonElement result : results) {

        JsonObject resultObj        = result.getAsJsonObject();

        String PackingSlipURL       = resultObj.get("packing_slip_url").getAsString();
        String StickerURL           = resultObj.get("sticker_url").getAsString();
        String ShippingPartner      = resultObj.get("shipping_partner").getAsString();
        String id                   = resultObj.get("id").getAsString();

        printPDFFromURL(PackingSlipURL, "HP-idealbetalingen-printer");
        printPDFFromURL(StickerURL, "Zebra?");

        //JsonObject deletedFromQueue   = sendPost("deletefromqueue/"+id);

    }

}

}
```

Comment: you might be missing a dependency

Comment: @JohnKane any clue which?

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44543287/294097

Comment: @JohnKane, I did in fact miss the required jempbox dependency, but now I've added it, but still get the same error.

Comment: did you add the dependancy for fontbox?

Comment: Yes. I added, fontbox, commons-logging and jempbox.

Comment: weird after downloading fontbox you should have gotten at least a different error. are you sure that the libraries are being added to your runtime libraries?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure about it; At least, if they are listed here: https://prnt.sc/is2tx1 it means they are included right?

Comment: I believe so, maybe there is a version that doesnt match? or that method was removed from later versions of fontbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@self; indeed as John Kane suggested, it had to do with version numbering. I was trying to use a 2.x.x version of fontbox with a 1.8.x version of pdfbox.